# Generating G-code from Mathematica

Tags: graphics, export

Has anybody generated G-code (used for controlling milling machines and plotters and other hardware) in Mathematica? High quality inexpensive plotters have reached the market and I would like to drive one directly from Mathematica if possible.

A related question was asked on Reddit last year (https://www.reddit.com/r/Mathematica/comments/3ouex6/gcode_using_mathematica/) but I suspect greater expertise exists here.

Comment: There are many G-code subsets around. As for Line (2/3D) and Circle (2D) primitives , the translation should be straightforward. Perhaps you can add a sample path? Generation in the sense of subtractive CAM (milling)  from generic 2D/3D objects can become arbitrarily complex though...

Comment: @YvesKlett My needs are very basic, purely two-dimensional. That said, I've no experience with G-code and I'm wary of starting from scratch. I may end up with a Mathematica -> DXF -> Python -> GCode chain, however inelegant.

Comment: I coded a postprocessor for an obscure CNC-code (.ncp) years ago. That can be done with a few lines... if you add an example with *Mathematica* primitives and expected G-code output,  that should help getting you there... especially if you don't need directed arcs and only lines/polylines.

Comment: Michael, how about adding that example? This is a good question...